# Variational methods - explaining theory expression

Tags: probability, expectation-maximization, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

Could anyone explain unrolling the following equation? I do not see how the difference is equal to Kullback-Leibler equation.

$$
\mathcal{L} (\theta) - \mathcal{F}(q,x) = \log p(y|\theta) - \int{q(x) \log \frac{p(x|y, \theta) p(y|\theta)}{q(x)}dx} = - \int{q(x) \log \frac{p(x|y, \theta) }{q(x)}dx} = KL(q, p(x|y, \theta))
$$

Source: [Variational Methods, Zoubin Ghahramani](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10-702/Zoubin-702.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's clearer this way
$$KL(q, p(x|y, \theta)) + \mathcal{F}(q,x)$$$$ = \int{q(x) \log \frac{q(x) }{p(x|y, \theta)}dx} + \int{q(x) \log \frac{p(x|y, \theta) p(y|\theta)}{q(x)}dx} $$$$= \int{q(x) \{\log \frac{p(x|y, \theta) p(y|\theta)}{q(x)}+\log \frac{q(x) }{p(x|y, \theta)}\}dx}$$$$=\int q(x) \log p(y|\theta) dx$$$$=\log p(y|\theta)=\mathcal{L} (\theta)$$

---

Note that in some other literature $\mathcal{L}$ might refer to the lower bound instead.